# In vim how do I auto shift-back a tab space when closing a tag

Tags: vim

E.g. if I have

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    </html>
```

`</html>` should shift back to be inline with the other tag, I've tried googling things like my title but all I can find is "Quick ways to indent files" which just leaves me with `gg=G`

Sorry for the poor and straight forward question, there isn't much detail I can give in this one.

Comment: You could use `<<` but I don't know of an *automatic* solution.

Comment: I hit ctrl-D when typing the </html>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default HTML indent script was changed during the 7.3-7.4 transition and it now requires a few settings to actually work correctly: `:help html-indenting`.

This is what I have in my `vimrc`:

```
let g:html_indent_script1 = 'inc'
let g:html_indent_style1  = 'inc'
let g:html_indent_inctags = 'html,body,head,tbody,p,li,dd,dt,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,blockquote'
```

With these settings, all your closing tags should move to column 0 by themselves when you type the closing `>`.

If you do a lot of HTML, you should try [Sparkup](https://github.com/rstacruz/sparkup) or [Emmet](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim).